# SpriteKit iPhone/iPhoneX/iPad sizing issue

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am almost done developing a game for ios. I was not planning on supporting the iPhoneX in the beginning, but it looks like I would be cutting off a good portion of users since the new xs as well.
Unfortunately I chose the ipad size as standard at the beginning, and now I am not sure how to deal with the iPhone X screen since the sides are really cut off and everything looks zoomed. Is there a way to set the safe area below the cutout of the status bar, and above the home button, basically to a normal iphone ratio?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try to solve the problem by setting **scene.scaleMode** in your *GameViewController*.

I personally set that to `scene.scaleMode = .fill`, but there are 4 options if it wouldn't suit you. You can see the options in this 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icrkh.png).

If that doesn't help you can specify **UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom** for each type of device individually. You can see the options in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSm7h.png)

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone{
    // for iPhone 
    scene.scaleMode = .fill
}
else {
    // other
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
}
```

I hope that helped you.